# How to configure grafana to display data in graphite

Tags: configuration, graphite, grafana

I am trying to configure grafana for graphite. I used the below link to configure graphite.
Graphite is running on my laptop on port 8080. I am able to send data using a sample project that i have created and am able to see the graphs for the same on graphite UI.I am sending data to graphite over port 2003 ie the port on which carbon runs.
Graphite installation - https://gist.github.com/albertohm/5697429

I am trying to configure grafana now to display data present on graphite.I have used the link below to configure grafana. I have only made changes in the config file.When i click the index.html file i can see the grafana UI but it is not displaying data present on graphite. Can somebody please help me on this.
Grafana installation link - http://grafana.org/docs/

All the services are running on my laptop.

Below is the config file that i am using on grafana.

```
define(['settings'],
function (Settings) {


  return new Settings({


    datasources: {
      graphite: {
        type: 'graphite',
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        default: true,
        //render_method: 'GET',
      }
    },


    /* Global configuration options
    * ========================================================
    */

    // specify the limit for dashboard search results
    search: {
      max_results: 20
    },

    // default home dashboard
    default_route: '/dashboard/file/default.json',
    //default_route: '/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/dashboard',

    // set to false to disable unsaved changes warning
    unsaved_changes_warning: true,

    // set the default timespan for the playlist feature
    // Example: "1m", "1h"
    playlist_timespan: "1m",

    // If you want to specify password before saving, please specify it bellow
    // The purpose of this password is not security, but to stop some users from accidentally changing dashboards
    admin: {
      password: ''
    },

    // Change window title prefix from 'Grafana - <dashboard title>'
    window_title_prefix: 'Grafana - ',

    // Add your own custom panels
    plugins: {
      // list of plugin panels
      panels: [],
      // requirejs modules in plugins folder that should be loaded
      // for example custom datasources
      dependencies: [],
    }

  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added any graph trying to pull metrics from Graphite? If you have so, try debugging with Chrome DevTools / Firebug, watching the AJAX calls.

Comment: I am getting a JSON parse error when trying to open the graph mozilla or any other browser.I have put all the details in the below answer.

Comment: Please don't add details in an answer. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Is your Graphite instance protected by HTTP authentication? Try opening `/metrics/find/?query=*` pasting the URL in the URL bar using the same browser you use to show Grafana.